# Application of Open Mapping Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

This was stated without proof in the complex analysis text I am reading (*Complex Made Simple* by Ulrich, page 107). I'm sure it's easy, but I'm tired and need a little help.

Let $f$ be nonconstant and holomorphic in some region $V$ and assume $f'$ is nonconstant. Define

$$\Omega = \left\{ \frac{f(z)-f(w)}{z-w}: z,w\in V, z\neq w \right\}.$$

Why is $\Omega$ open? I don't see how to use the hypothesis that $f'$ is nonconstant.

To be clearer: I tried something like the answers below. But Ulrich specifically mentions that the hypothesis that $f'$ is nonconstant is needed in addition to the hypothesis that $f$ is nonconstant. So I feel I'm missing some subtle point about the derivative.

Edit: After reading the answers below, the key point is $f'$ nonconstant implies the difference quotient is nonconstant.

Comment: Doesn't it follow from open mapping theorem directly?

Comment: @Landscape I'm confused about the hypothesis that $f'$ is nonconstant.

Comment: Please see my answer.

Comment: While $\{(z,w) : z,w \in V, z \neq w \}$ is open in $\mathbb{C}^2$, it isn't obvious that the Open Mapping Thm. of complex variables can "directly" apply (since that is usually stated for a [holomorphic function of one variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis))).  I don't have Ulrich's book for comparison though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given $w\in V$, define
$$g_w(z):V\setminus\{w\}\to\mathbb C,\quad z\mapsto \frac{f(z)-f(w)}{z-w}.$$
Since $f$ is holomorphic on $V$ and since $f'$ is not constant, $g$ is a nonconstant holomorphic function on $V\setminus\{w\}$. Noting that $V\setminus\{w\}$ is open, by open mapping theorem, $g_w(V\setminus\{w\})$ is an open subset of $\mathbb C$.
It follows that 
$$\Omega=\bigcup_{w\in V}g_w(V\setminus\{w\})$$
is open.

Comment: Nice! We both wrote pretty much *exactly* the same answer nearly simultaneously ;-)

Comment: Thanks. The point I was missing is that we need to show that $g$ is nonconstant, and that $f'$ suffices to prove this.

Comment: @Potato: You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

If you let $$
  g_w(z) = \frac{f(z) - f(w)}{z-w}
$$
then $g_w$ is holomorphic on $V \setminus \{w\}$. Since $V \setminus \{x\} = V \cap \{x\}^C$ is the intersection of open sets, it's open. By the open mapping theorem $g_w(V \setminus \{w\})$ is thus open. Now observe that $$
  \Omega = \bigcup_{w \in V} g_w\left(V \setminus \{w\}\right)
$$
shows that $\Omega$ is a union of open sets and thus open.

Comment: This is what I tried, but I could not see where the hypothesis that $f'$ was nonconstant was used.

Comment: Because the open mapping theorem holds only for non-constant $f$. $f'$ is non-constant guarantees that $g$ is non-constant.

Comment: Ulrich is right, $f$ nonconstant is not enough to imply the difference quotient $g$ is nonconstant (but $f'$ nonconstant is).

Comment: Sorry, 2 minutes later than you with an almost identical answer with you, even the notations. Should I delete mine?

Comment: @hardmath Ah, I see now!

Comment: I worded that badly, using $f$ for two different things in my comment :-( You apply the open mapping theorem to $g$, so you need $g$ non-constant. Which you get from $f'$ being non-constant, since $g_w(z) \approx f'(z)$ around $w$.

Comment: @Landscape Yeah, the fact that we both chose to call the family of functions $g_w$ shows how deeply entrenched some notational conventions really are ;-)

Comment: @fgp: I also didn't notice you had left a comment under my answer before my comment to yours. Perhaps such a coincidence in using the same notation $g_w$ sounds natural because it came into my mind at first glance. However, it still makes me feel a little embarrassed. :)

Comment: @Landscape Well, to mine too ;-) And anyway, your answers is better than mine anyway because you clearly state where $f'$ non-constant is required, whereas I glossed over that. Which, given that the question *explicitly* asks for where it's required, really wasn't a particularly smart thing for me to do...

Comment: @fgp: Thank you for your understanding. Actually, I didn't intend to post an answer until Potato asked me why $f'$ is supposed to be non-constant. I think I would have also forgetten to mention that if I hadn't been asked that question.